# Deploying Outlook Add-in by region

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I can't seem to find an answer to this one in the MS docs, but I have an MS Outlook add-in, that due to some regulations, we would like to deploy across multiple web servers in different regions (US, EU, APAC, etc).

Is it possible, through the manifest.xml file, to target a specific web host based on the client's region. If not, is it possible to create multiple XML files and have the Office Store distribute them on a per region basis.

I'm trying to avoid having multiple per region add-ins available in the store and assuming the user will choose the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You simply use [Override element](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/override?product=outlook&version=v1.5) on your Url, as in [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial):

```
<bt:String id="insertGistLabel" DefaultValue="Insert Gist">
   <bt:Override Locale="es-ES" Value="Inserte el Gist"/>
</bt:String>
```

So in your case it would be something like:

```
<bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://[hostname]/index.html">
        <bt:Override Locale="es-ES" Value="https://[hostname]/el-indexo.html"/>    
    </bt:Url>
</bt:Urls>
```

You can add as many locale as you want.

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I was looking for, extra thanks for linking the docs!